# GA parameters are mising in rediecting second time

Tags: php, google-analytics, redirect

We have web site, Which register click then redirect to next web site.
Then again next web site register then redirect to client actual web site.

Problem is first level its working fine but on the 2nd level it missing GA Parameters.

> URL AS :
>   www.firstwebsite.com?adId=1212&link=http://www.secondwebsite.com?adId=1212&slotId=15&url=http://clientwebsite.com?campcode=XXXXXX&utm_source=XXXXXXXXX&utm_campaign=XXXXXXX

In above example at first level redirection working fine but at second level script register counted fine but while redirecting it missing two extra parameter from final url

Thses are missing parameter &utm_source=XXXXXXXXX&utm_campaign=XXXXXXX

Please help anyone..

Comment: what you mean bro...

Comment: As far as the browser is concerned ampersands are the delimiters between url parameters. So the utm parameters are treated not as a part of the redirect url, but as url parameters to the original url.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your URL:

```
www.firstwebsite.com?adId=1212&link=http://www.secondwebsite.com?adId=1212&slotId=15&url=http://clientwebsite.com?campcode=XXXXXX&utm_source=XXXXXXXXX&utm_campaign=XXXXXXX
```

You must escape the ampersands and last question mark because is a value of a parameter, not the last parameters.

You can escape them with javascript or in your server-side backend. That doesn't matter, but you need to escape them. An example in javascript:

```
 var str = "http://clientwebsite.com?campcode=XXXXXX&utm_source=XXXXXXXXX&utm_campaign=XXXXXXX";
 var final = "www.firstwebsite.com?adId=1212&link="+encodeURIComponent(str)
```

Result will be:

> `www.firstwebsite.com?adId=1212&link=http%3A%2F%2Fclientwebsite.com%3Fcampcode%3DXXXXXX%26utm_source%3DXXXXXXXXX%26utm_campaign%3DXXXXXXX`